# FileFinder using SQL

Tags: java, database, project

I was thinking of working on a project while I have some free time and this one looks pretty nice: http://mindprod.com/project/filefinder.html

One thing I'm wondering about is that will it really be much faster compared to the regular windows search if I use SQL? I'm planning to use MySQL since it's open source. Also, do I need to be good at databases for this? I have basic knowledge about relational databases and can definitely make some SQL statements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In unix there are commands like `find` and `locate`. It is much faster to find file using database based `locate`. I think Windows Search is also based on database so it will be hard to beat it.

As for database I would use [JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/) or embedded DB like SQLite. MySQL was bought by Oracle and in my private opinion there are better open source alternatives like PostgreSQL.

I think this task is quite easy from SQL point of view. For me the hardest part would be synchronizing database after there are changes in file system.